# How do you sync from USB?

Tags: sync, ankidroid

On AnkiDroid, how do you sync from USB?  I'm unable to find the option in settings.  Is it just a matter of having your device plugged in via USB and having AnkiDesktop open?

Answer (score 2):

AnkiDroid developer here.

It does not work so easily unfortunately.

Right now the easiest/safest would be:

1. Export your decks as an APKG file
2. Copy the APKG file over USB
3. Open the APKG file in Anki Desktop

---

There is a more convenient solution but it is very difficult to set up initially:

1. Set up Android to to Ethernet over USB
2. Install your own sync server
3. Compile AnkiDroid with your own sync URL

Comment: With ADB running on the computer (see e.g. [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575)), would there be anything to ease the job? Or would that be an idea for a future version of *AnkiDesktop* maybe? Not using it myself, just suggesting ;)

Comment: @Izzy: Indeed copying the SQLite files over USB with adb pull/push sometimes work, but it breaks things when the database is not properly closed, so it is very dangerous and not recommended.

Comment: I rather thought about something implemented into Anki: Dektop triggers an Intent, which exports the data and gives back the `/path/to/file.apkg`, which then can be "pulled" by the Desktop (raw idea, but you get it). Would be an easier variant of your first approach then – with the difference of the user just having to "push a button" in AnkiDesk :)

Comment: Put it on your Todo list and mark it as "patches/pull-requests welcome" then, linked from the README so visitors of the [project's Github page](https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android) can't miss it :)

Comment: Done: https://code.google.com/p/ankidroid/issues/detail?id=2397 There are currently 679 enhancement requests and all are waiting for volunteers :-)